# ArrayList method "lastIndexOf" returning -1 when item does exist in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get the basics of `ArrayList`s, but I can't get the `lastIndexOf` method to work properly. As you can see in my code below, the program runs and should print "1", the index of the number 3, but prints "-1" instead (which should be printed only if 3 didn't exist in the `ArrayList`). What's my problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Pile {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = {1,3,23,4};
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
            myList.add(myArray[0]);
        }
        System.out.println(myList.lastIndexOf(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code in your questions. It's much better to copy and paste the code as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only adding the first element of `myArray` to `myList`

You should replace

```
myList.add(myArray[0]);
```

with this

```
myList.add(myArray[i]);
```

Also, instead of manually copying the elements, you could use [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) (but you would need to change the type of `myArray` to `Integer[]`):

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
```

Comment: Using Arrays.asList on an array of ints would result in a List<int[]>, so it won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

You are only adding the first element of the array multiple times to the list.

```
myList.add(myArray[0]);
```

That's why your list doesn't contain 3.

Change it to

```
myList.add(myArray[i]);
```